# android rxjava observable fromCallable onNext function not call after proguard activated

Tags: android, proguard, rx-java, observable

**EDIT SOLUTION :** Do not use following combination if you have same situation.

**RxJava, Jack & Jill Java 8 Support and Proguard**

I disabled Jack & Jill from my gradle file and added retro lambda plugin for lambda support. Problem solved !

**proguard-rules.pro** should contains RxJava rules below :

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}
```

**QUESTION**

I'm using `Observable's fromCallable` function to produce test data. The code working well **without proguard** but when I **activated proguard**, `Subscription's onNext` function does not call.

**Observable Call**

```
public void loadNearbyUserEvents() {
    Log.w(TAG, "loadNearbyUserEvents");
    try {
        getMvpView().showProgress();

        Subscription subscription = dataManager.getEventImplementer().getNearbyUsersEvents()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(getSubscriber());

        subscriptions.add(subscription);

        Log.w(TAG, "aaaa");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        getMvpView().showError(e.getMessage());
        getMvpView().hideProgress();
    }
}

private Subscriber<List<Event>> getSubscriber() {
    return new Subscriber<List<Event>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onError");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Event> events) {
            Log.w(TAG, "size of list : " + events.size());
            getMvpView().hideProgress();

            if (events.size() == 0) {
                getMvpView().showEmpty();
                return;
            }

            getMvpView().showEvents(events);
        }
    };
}
```

**EventImplementer's getNearbyUserEvents**

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Event>> getNearbyUsersEvents() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> EventProducer.produce(20));
}
```

this above codes working well without proguard.

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
    # Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in D:\developer\Android\Application\windows\android-sdk-windows/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}



# okhttp rulez
-dontwarn okio.**
# okhttp rulezzz


# retrofit rulez
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
# retrofit rulezzz


# searchView rulez
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.widget.SearchView {
   public <init>(android.content.Context);
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
# searchview rulezzz


# parcel rulez
-keep interface org.parceler.Parcel
-keep @org.parceler.Parcel class * { *; }
-keep class **$$Parcelable { *; }
# parcel rulezzz


# picasso rulez
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
# picasso rulezzz


# rx rulez
# rxjava
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    long producerNode;
    long consumerNode;
}
# rx rulezzz
```

what is wrong with my code ? why just onCompleted function works but onNext and onError functions does not call ?

**NOTE : When I use `Observable.just(() -> EventProducer.produce(20))` function it is working.**

Comment: Hey I got exactly the same problem. Do you found a solution?

Comment: yes, I wrote solution to the question post's head. **If you are using jack to java 8 features, you should disable it too**. you can use **retrolambda plugin** if you need lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

hey with RxJava I use this rules

```
# rxjava
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}
```

Maybe it would help.

cheers

Comment: I changed my rules with your proguard rules but it is producing error and crashing application. logcat is : `java.lang.InternalError
 at rx.e.a.b.b.b(:115)
 at rx.e.a.b.c.<clinit>(:34)
 at rx.e.a.m.d(:154)
 at rx.e.a.m.<init>(:58)
 at rx.e.a.m.<init>(:37)
 at rx.e.a.q.<init>(:264)
 at rx.e.a.aa.<clinit>(:264)
 at rx.a.g(:7334)`

Comment: try update. btw you don't need to add android sdk classes to proguard

Comment: previous error is gone but it is still same. onNext function does not get call.

Comment: I checked, there is no error. it is weird. I put every try catch blocks to print error message and subsription's onError throw message. there is none.